# SSRS line chart - seemingly simple but apparently not so

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I have only used SSRS for tables before, now I need to know how to do a line chart, but I think it requires using expressions in a way that is not straightforward to me after googling on how SSRS works.  I have googled for over two hours but it is still unclear to me how I am supposed to handle this, as the group expression syntax that I have found doesn't seem to be sufficient to solve this problem.

I need a report that will tell the total number of days that patients stayed in beds per month.  In each stay table is the patient's admit date and discharge date.  So the amount of days that one patient would stay in the bed per month would be the discharge date - admit date, not including any days before the beginning of the month or after the end of the month.

So I want the total number of bed days for all patients per month.  So let's say there was one patient who stayed from February 10th-March 5th and another patient who stayed from March 10th-March 15th, and there were no other patients at the hospital (to make it simple), then for the month of February, the plotted value should be 11 (March 1-5 = 5 for patient 1 + March 10-15 = 6 for patient 2)

I don't quite understand how to specify the interval (every month), and then within that month how to get the total number of bed days for all patients.  Mathematically, I understand it, but since I am new to SSRS charts, I have no idea how to do it programatically.  Especially since I need to somehow specify either in the expression or elsewhere "get the month start date and get the month end date for the current month" and then also plot each expression on the current month (or something like that).  I know that I can use expressions to do sums or use variables, but how I piece this all together out of the information that I find on the internet about SSRS is still a mystery to me.

Also, I want to find the data at a given hospital, so I would want to have a way of using a hospital id parameter passed in code behind and then applying this id to the group expression somehow to filter it.

Any help would be great, the more the better.

I am using Visual Studio 2013, but I assume it is likely that people familiar with SSRS in 2012 or 2010 or possibly even earlier may be able to provide helpful information that may carry over

Comment: You probably just need to read some tutorials and work your way through this. SSRS hasn't changed much since 2008 R2. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522859%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) are some good step-by-step tutorials. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx#VisualBasicFunctions) are some expression examples. You can use the month and year functions to group your dates. The step-by-step reports explain how to use parameters.

Comment: SELECT AdmitDate AS 'AdmitDate', DischargeDate AS 'DischargeDate'  FROM ....

=Sum(Fields!AdmitDate.Value

Comment: I have some idea now, but what I need to know is how to say in my group expression "The beginning of THIS month, the end of THIS month", and assign the grouping based on months.. can someone help me with this? I basically do an sql select of AdmitDate and DischargeDate, then my query is
=Sum((Fields.AdmitDate.Value >= monthBegin && Fields.DischargeDate.Value <= monthEnd), (Fields!DischargeDate.Day.Value - Fields!AdmitDate.Day.Value + 1), etc... but of course this is not correct syntax.  I need to figure out how to get the monthEnd and monthDay to refer to the grouping and set the grouping

Comment: Are your months not the same as the calendar month?  If they are the same you can just group by month and year using the functions.  If they aren't, you need a calendar table that you can use to bring the appropriate month and year as fields in your query.